# Work with real time interactive trading chart with a different time frame

Tags: curated-data, charts, finance

I would to work with real time interactive trading chart, for example:

[image]

which is the daily chart of Dow Jones Industrial Index

But, the problem is that Mathematica "InteractiveTradingChart" function gives me only daily, weekly, and monthly time frame by default.

So, how I could do to obtain the same candlestick chart, but in different customized time frame, for example at 1 minute, 10 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, 4 hour... and so on ??

Updated:
->Clarification: My aim is not to "limit" the interval of data range, ma to define candlestick chart where each bar is given buy a customized time frame.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you can limit the date range to five days, but not less:

```
InteractiveTradingChart[{"GOOGL", {{2020, 1, 1}, {2020, 1, 5}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried both your solution, but it seems doesn't work anyway.
Mathematica gives me the following error message:
InteractiveTradingChart::ldata: {DJ,{{2018,1,5,9,20,1},{2018,1,5,9,30,1}}} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

Comment: My aim is not to "limit" the data range, ma to define candlestick chart where each bar is given buy a customized time frame